# How to refresh monorepo TypeScript types in VS Code without reloading the window

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, monorepo

I have an open source project called [`react-querybuilder`](https://react-querybuilder.js.org) that is maintained as a [monorepo](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder). Most of the TypeScript type definitions live in the [`ts` package](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/tree/main/packages/ts).

When I have a file open in VS Code for one of the other packages that imports a type from `@react-querybuilder/ts`, the types seemed to be cached based on the `packages/ts/dist` folder at the time VS Code launches.

When I make an update to a type in the `ts` folder and rebuild the `@react-querybuilder/ts` package, the change is not automatically applied to the other projects, even if I close and reopen all the files.

The only way I have found to update the types cache is to reload the VS Code window. Unfortunately my work computer is old and not built as a great developer machine, so this can take some time. Is there a way to refresh the types without completely reloading the window?

Comment: You could try using the "TypeScript: Restart TS Server" command (`typescript.restartTsServer`) instead, as it's a bit faster than a full reload.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be good enough. Thanks! If you add that as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There might be some optimization to your codebase that prevents this problem from occurring, but in the mean time, there's a **"TypeScript: Restart TS Server"** command that refreshes the types and is a bit faster than reloading the entire window. You can also use it to update the types after installing new npm packages.

I personally find these two keyboard shortcuts useful: `alt+r` restarts TypeScript, whereas `alt+command+r` reloads the window.

```
  {
    "key": "alt+r",
    "command": "typescript.restartTsServer"
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.reloadWindow"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks again! Yeah I'm sure there's something else I can do so the packages read directly from each other's source `*.ts` files to get their types instead of the `*.d.ts` in the `dist` folder, just not sure how that would work yet.

Comment: You're welcome! Depending on your setup you might be able to get some value out of `npm link`: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link